# AWS Offline Jobscheduler

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, scheduler

I want to run offline job through AWS. I have a php file called test.php. It have some insert statements. I want to trigger the file through AWS Lambda. Is it possible. If it Possible means how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that `test.php` file is on a PHP server somewhere which is accessible from an HTTP request, then yes, you can write some Java/C#/Python/NodeJS code in AWS Lambda that will trigger it for you.

If you're thinking of executing your PHP code *in* AWS Lambda itself, unfortunately you can't (without hacking it) because PHP is not a supported runtime.

Comment: I am using following code.It works fine                                                 
                                                                                                              
 'use strict';
var http = require('http');
console.log('Creating a simple HTTP request');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    http.get("http://example.com/test.php", function(res)
    {
  var body = ''; // Will contain the final response
  // Received data is a buffer.
  // Adding it to our body
  res.on('data', function(data){
    body += data;
  });
})    
};